# What did I do wrong? Inverting amplifier 1:1 ratio

Tags: resistors, inverting-amplifier

[image: schematic]
[image: Board]

I'm getting a non inverted output. The resistors I used were two 100ohm 1/4watts. Signal was 4v peak to peak 600hz.

Comment: My memory might be rusty on this, but shouldn't you supply power to the power pins of the opamp too?

Comment: Preferably not with your signal, that you now mysteriously call Vcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quad op-amps require pin 4 and pin 11 connected to Vsupply+ and Vsupply- for them to work. For your circuit to work (inverting Vcc to -Vcc) you need a negative supply on pin 11 that is greater in magnitude than Vcc for this to work.

Once you have this right you need to choose resistor values that are higher than 100 ohms because 100 ohms will take 50 mA from the op-amp output if Vcc is 5 volts.

Comment: Also, no using Vcc as the input voltage.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast this is why I specified power rails differently.

Comment: Well, yes, but that implies that you DO specify power rails.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast which is why I said "you need a negative supply on pin 11 that is greater in magnitude than Vcc for this to work"

Comment: @user96033 what is it that you don't understand about this answer? If you do now understand the answer and it tells you what you needed to know (rather than want you wanted to know LOL), then please consider formally marking it as accepted.

Comment: @Andyaka I can now appreciate the conciseness of this answer! Simply misinterpreted the Vsupply+/- terminology as Vcc/GND (being entirely new to the concept of AC circuitry). Which is why I raised a follow-up question.

Comment: @Andyaka I got the circuit to work by the way! Made it to state science fair today thanks to you and the rest of the community.